# how to change the requestURL using filter or servlet

Tags: url, servlets, request, port, servlet-filters

how to change the requestURL  using filter or servlet  .

for example if request is "http://servername1:8080"
I want to change the same to "http://servername2:7001"

Comment: This approach does not work. Fortunately this one works great http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url

Answer (score 19):

Add the following [servlet filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) to your application:

```
public class RequestUrlRewritingFilter implements Filter {

    //Empty init()/destroy() here

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapped = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
            @Override
            public StringBuffer getRequestURL() {
                final StringBuffer originalUrl = ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getRequestURL();
                return new StringBuffer("http://servername2:7001");
            }
        };
        chain.doFilter(wrapped, response);
    }
}
```

All requests you want to intercept must go through it. As you can see it takes original `request` method and overrides `getRequestURL()` method by returning a different value. You still have access to the original request if you want to base new URL on the old one.

At the end you must continue processing the request `chain.doFilter()` but by providing wrapped request, not the original one.

Comment: at my end I am having this error:
The constructor HttpServletRequestWrapper(ServletRequest) is undefined

Comment: Rabia, you may need to pass HttpServletRequest to the wrapper constructor

Answer (score 3):

The above is a good solution compared to many others on the web that use .forward() as that breaks the filter chain. This solution allows subsequent filters to process the request after is has been modified.

But there are 2 additional methods that must implemented in order for this to be 'transparent' to downstream filter processing, and they must present the same modification of the URL to present a consistent request object. The wrapper must implement:

```
@Override
public String getRequestURI() {
    final String originalUri = ((HttpServletRequest)getRequest()).getRequestURI();
    return "/"; // Must be consistent with getRequestURL()
}
@Override
public String getServletPath() {
    final String originalPath = ((HttpServletRequest)getRequest()).getServletPath();
    return "/"; // Must be consistent with getRequestURL()
}
```