# How to change HTTP link dynamically

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, hyperlink, request

In a Servlet, using the code:

```
String requestURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
```

I receive the URL: http://localhost:8080/TV/admin/adminView.do

How can I change this link dynamically?

The final link should be: http://localhost:8080/TV/file.txt (i.e. `http:// + server + client + file.txt`).

Comment: That's the request URL. You can't modify that. Even if you could, it wouldn't do anything. Are you asking how to do a redirect?

Comment: I need to find out if exists the file (file.txt) on this server and client.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: When the file.txt exists on this server and with this client (server and client can be different) I want to display the link to view this file, but only if the file exists. Some clients do not have such file, for example the link http://ctva/stag/file.txt - works fine, but the link http://ctvb/graphs/file.txt - does not exist.

Comment: So the client can "see the link" only if he has it and the server has it? What on earth are you trying to do? In any case you're way off.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a look at:

[How to use a servlet filter in Java to change an incoming servlet request url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url)

or

[how to change the requestURL using filter or servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652957/how-to-change-the-requesturl-using-filter-or-servlet)

bye