# Spring MVC request and response flow explanation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations

I can't find correct client request flow in below syntax.Could someone please clarify what is happening here?

```
Client(1) --> Dispatcher Servlet(2) --> Handler Mapping(3) --> Controller(4) -->
ModelAndView(5) --> viewResolver(6) --> View(7) --> Client(1)
```

If possible please specify what are the corresponding spring classes/interfaces used in spring MVC process.

Comment: read section 7.1 [here](http://www.manning.com/walls4/Sample-Ch07.pdf) for basics and complete chapter 7 for end to end understanding.

Comment: http://javadecodedquestions.blogspot.in/2013/03/understanding-spring-mvc.html

Comment: You can find good explanation here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/14015907/3425489](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14015907/3425489)

Comment: [How Spring MVC Framework works? How HTTP Request is processed?](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-spring-mvc-framework-works-web-flow.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Request will be received by `DispatcherServlet`.
2. `DispatcherServlet` will take the help of `HandlerMapping` and get to know the `@Controller` class name associated with the given request.
3. So request transfer to the `@Controller`, and then `@Controller` will process the request by executing appropriate methods and returns `ModelAndView` object (contains Model data and View name) back to the DispatcherServlet
4. Now `DispatcherServlet` send the model object to the `ViewResolver` to get the actual view page.
5. Finally, `DispatcherServlet` will pass the Model object to the View page to display the result.

Comment: Thank's Harshal Patil.

Comment: The first request will be received by `DispatcherServlet`. The first request?

Answer (score 1):

> Spring Flow
>   First  Request from JSP/HTML will hit the dispacher servlet,
>   Based on the xml file it will go to particular controller,
>   After going to controller it search for request mapping , based on request mapping it will go to the particular method and follows instructions and takes the model and view and give it to view resolver via dispacher servlet and view resolver will display the view.

Answer (score 0):

I supplement the above explanations. request flow is like below.

Client --> WAS(go through filters) --> DispatcherServlet.doService, doDispatch --> Dispatcher Servlet.handlerMapping,hanlderAdapter --> Controller return ModelAndView --> DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult, render, resolveViewName --> View --> Client.

I think debugging DispatcherServlet's methods with break points is a good way to understand request flow.