# How Spring rest services are handled internally

Tags: java, spring, rest, servlets, spring-restcontroller

I am building `rest services` in `Spring`. If I am not wrong, `web services` are `servlets` i.e. internally they get converted into servlet.

So, just wondering, does all service methods(methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`) gets converted into separate servlet?

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015642/how-does-the-dispatcherservlet-resolver-and-controllers-interact

Answer (score 2):

Actually nothing's *converted* into Servlet.

Spring brings its own [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) - which maps to "everything below" a given path.

All `@Controller`s will be invoked by that `DispatchServlet` and not directly by the servlet engine (like tomcat or jetty). So theres no need to convert to servlet.