# URL access controll by IP in Tomcat7

Tags: url, ip, tomcat7, access-control

I need to control URL access according to client IP on tomcat 7.0.39
This is what I found 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter

but I can't understand all from it.
Do you have any additional examples, totorials etc.

what I actually need is to allow all IPs access, eg. `"http://base_url/a/b/c"`
and allow localhost/127.0.0.1 access  `"http://base_url/a"`

I couldn't understand how to match "any" IP or if i need multiple filters or multiple entries within the filter.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you need protect only `/base_url/a`, since other addresses are opened to all IPs. Define 2 filters. First to allow local access by IP, second by localhost:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>RemoteAddressFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>allow</param-name>
    <param-value>127.0.0.1|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>deny</param-name>
    <param-value>192\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+</param-value>
  </init-param>   
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>RemoteAddressFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/a/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<filter>
  <filter-name>RemoteHostFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteHostFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>allow</param-name>
    <param-value>localhost</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>RemoteHostFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/a/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it just fails to block external access. any ideas?

Comment: with the example on Tomcat documentation (url-pattern="/*") external IPs are blocked for the whole web site (/a/b/c) with url-pattern = "/a/*" no one is blocked.

Comment: I have updated the example. Use `<param-name>deny</param-name>`. You should find the configuration that fit your needs

Comment: I played with it some more but as soon as I have "deny" on ".*", the "allow" is ignored (also after changing the order of allow and deny)

Comment: The order of init parameters is not important.
add to test some external IP for deny of `<param-value>192\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+</param-value>` RemoteAddressFilter. remove `deny` from RemoteHostFilter

Answer (score 0):

If the filter you are writing doesn't work the way you are expecting to, you could always implement your own using the javax.servlet.Filter API (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html).

There are a couple examples here:

- [How to use a servlet filter in Java to change an incoming servlet request url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url)
- http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-filter-and-how-do-i-use-it.html

Writing a Servlet Filter is straightforward and you can make it achieve more than just IP filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,

Eventually I created my own filter
this is how:

- create class that extends BaseFilter and implament doFilter.
- required jar files: catalina.jar, servlet_api.jar, tomcat_juli.jar
- in the do filter running chain.doFilter means continue filter this connection (or use it if no more 
  filters exists)
- an init method can also be used to read params from web.xml (where you put the filter configuration)
- add your new jar (with the filter to Tomcat's lib directory)
  add the jar name to Tomcat/conf/catalina.properties default jar scanner

BR.