# Setting up multi lingual seo friendly site with struts

Tags: java, servlets, seo, struts, multilingual

I have an old web application made with struts 1.3 and I need to change the way the multilanguage works inside.
Currently I have an action that handles the change of language this way:

> ```
> this.setLocale(request, new Locale("es", "", ""));
> this.setLocale(request, new Locale("en", "", ""));
> this.setLocale(request, new Locale("fr", "", ""));
> this.setLocale(request, new Locale("pt", "", ""));
> // this is and instance of org.apache.struts.action.Action
> ```

Everything works fine, but now I'm requiered to change the language from the URL, that is, `http://www.example.com/en/index.do` should show the page in **English** and `http://www.example.com/es/index.do` would do so in **Spanish**.

Do you know how can I implement this?

I've been thinking in setting a servlet before the org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet (by extending ActionServlet) that parses the URL, changes the language if necessary and then continue with `super.doGet(request, response);` but the rest of the website's links will not have the language in the URL. `http://www.example.com/index.do`

**----- Edit:**
I've found a partial solution for this in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url):

I've created a filter and added it to the web.xml file

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LangFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.company.struts.LanguageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LangFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

and a `javax.servlet.Filter` class

```
public class LanguageFilter implements Filter {
[...]

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
    if (requestURI.indexOf("/context/en/") != -1) {
        String newURI = requestURI.replace("/context/en/", "/");
        req.getRequestDispatcher(newURI).forward(req, res);
    }
    else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
}
```

But now I have to change all the html:form and html:link tags from

```
<html:link action="/test2">Old link</html:link>
```

to

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/${sessionScope["org.apache.struts.action.LOCALE"]}/test2.do">New link</a>
```

Is there a way to intercept the response generated so I can modify those *.do URIs and add them the language parameter??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally come up with a solution to modify the links before sending the response.
These are my classes in case it helps someone else.

This is my filter:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.struts.Globals;

public class LanguageFilter implements Filter
{
    // ************************************************************************
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;

    // ************************************************************************
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
    {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    // ************************************************************************
    public void destroy()
    {
    }

    // ************************************************************************
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        GenericResponseWrapper wrapper = new GenericResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
        HttpServletRequest hrequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String servletPath = hrequest.getServletPath();

        String servletPathLowCase = servletPath.toLowerCase();

        String lang = "";
        String newURI = "/";
        if (servletPathLowCase.startsWith("/es/"))
        {
            lang = "es";
            newURI += servletPath.substring(4, servletPath.length());
        }
        else if (servletPathLowCase.startsWith("/en/"))
        {
            lang = "en";
            newURI += servletPath.substring(4, servletPath.length());
        }
        else if (servletPathLowCase.startsWith("/fr/"))
        {
            lang = "fr";
            newURI += servletPath.substring(4, servletPath.length());
        }
        else if (servletPathLowCase.startsWith("/pt/"))
        {
            lang = "pt";
            newURI += servletPath.substring(4, servletPath.length());
        }

        log.debug("language: '" + lang + "'; newURI: '" + newURI + "'");

        if (!"".equals(lang))
        {
            hrequest.getSession().setAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY, new Locale(lang));
            request.getRequestDispatcher(newURI).forward(request, wrapper);
        }
        else
        {
            chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);
        }

        if (wrapper.getContentType().equals("text/html"))
        {
            String langStruts = hrequest.getSession().getAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY).toString();
            // if ("".equals(langStruts))
            // langStruts = "es";
            String htmlResponseStruts = wrapper.toString();
            if ("".equals(lang))
            {
                // This URI is the requested URI for the section on the website where I have links to change language
                String uriForLanguages = servletPath + ("".equals(hrequest.getQueryString()) ? "" : "?" + hrequest.getQueryString());
                htmlResponseStruts = modifyStrutsLinks(htmlResponseStruts, langStruts, uriForLanguages);
            }

            // log.debug("htmlResponseStruts: " + htmlResponseStruts.toString());
            out.write(htmlResponseStruts);
        }
        else
            out.write(wrapper.toString());
        out.close();
    }

    // ************************************************************************
    private String modifyStrutsLinks(String htmlResponseStruts, String langStruts, String uriForLanguages)
    {
        String result = htmlResponseStruts;
        // REGEX: "([a-zA-Z0-9-_/])*\.do([a-zA-Z0-9-_?&=])*"
        // Regex explained from http://www.myregextester.com/index.php
        /**<code>
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
          "                        '"'
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
          (                        group and capture to \1 (0 or more times
                                   (matching the most amount possible)):
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            [a-zA-Z0-9-_/]           any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                                     'Z', '0' to '9', '-', '_', '/'
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
          )*                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                                   quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                                   repetition of the captured pattern will be
                                   stored in \1)
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
          \.                       '.'
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
          do                       'do'
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
          (                        group and capture to \2 (0 or more times
                                   (matching the most amount possible)):
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            [a-zA-Z0-9-_?&=]         any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                                     'Z', '0' to '9', '-', '_', '?', '&', '='
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
          )*                       end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                                   quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                                   repetition of the captured pattern will be
                                   stored in \2)
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
          "                        '"'
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        </code>*/
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([a-zA-Z0-9-_/])*\\.do([a-zA-Z0-9-_?&=])*\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlResponseStruts);

        List<String> listMatches = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (matcher.find())
        {
            listMatches.add(matcher.group(0));
        }

        for (String sUrl : listMatches)
        {
            int lastSlash = sUrl.lastIndexOf("/");
            if (lastSlash == -1)
                lastSlash = 0;
            String replacement = sUrl.substring(0, lastSlash + 1) + langStruts + "/" + sUrl.substring(lastSlash + 1);
            // log.debug("modifyStrutsLinks: " + sUrl + " ->: " + replacement);
            result = result.replace(sUrl, replacement);
        }

        // Replaces links written this way on the JSP <a href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/fr/ServletPathForReplacement"
        result = result.replace("/ServletPathForReplacement", uriForLanguages);
        return result;
    }

    // ************************************************************************
}
```

And these are the other classes GenericResponseWrapper.java

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

public class GenericResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper
{
    private ByteArrayOutputStream output;

    private int contentLength;

    private String contentType;

    private ServletOutputStream outputStream;

    PrintWriter printWriter;

    public GenericResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        super(response);
        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        outputStream = new FilterServletOutputStream(output);
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream, true); // true means auto-flush
    }

    public byte[] getData()
    {
        return output.toByteArray();
    }

    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException
    {
        return outputStream;
    }

    public PrintWriter getWriter()
    {
        return printWriter;
    }

    public void setContentLength(int length)
    {
        this.contentLength = length;
        super.setContentLength(length);
    }

    public int getContentLength()
    {
        return contentLength;
    }

    public void setContentType(String type)
    {
        this.contentType = type;
        super.setContentType(type);
    }

    public String getContentType()
    {
        return contentType;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String salida = "";
        try
        {
            // To modify the encoding
            salida =  output.toString("ISO-8859-1");
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return salida;
    }
}
```

And FilterServletOutputStream.java

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;

public class FilterServletOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream
{
    public ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;

    public DataOutputStream stream;

    public FilterServletOutputStream()
    {
        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        stream = new DataOutputStream(output);
    }

    public FilterServletOutputStream(ByteArrayOutputStream output)
    {
        this.output = output;
        stream = new DataOutputStream(output);
    }

    public void write(int b) throws IOException
    {
        stream.write(b);
    }

    public void write(byte b[]) throws IOException
    {
        stream.write(b);
    }

    public void write(byte buf[], int offset, int len) throws IOException
    {
        stream.write(buf, offset, len);
    }

    public void flush() throws IOException
    {
        stream.flush();
    }

    public void close() throws IOException
    {
        stream.close();
    }

    public ByteArrayOutputStream getBuffer()
    {
        return output;
    }

}
```