# Serving Static Content from same directory as service - Dropwizard

Tags: filter, jersey, servlet-filters, dropwizard, static-content

I am building a Dropwizard app to replace a legacy webserver, due to a lot of links pointing at this server, I have to be backwards compatible and support all kinds of resources that the legacy server used to serve.

The problem is that I have a bunch of static JS files being served from the same directory/path as the services themselves. Apparently you can't serve both types (service and static) from a single directory. so if I add the static bundle (now located in the resources directory), like so:

```
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/javascript", "/media"));
```

The dynamic services (served from /media/)  start returning 404
if I comment it, the dynamic services work fine.

As I said, I can't change any of the links, static or dynamic... 
Any suggestions?

### Update:

Resolved, here is a working example inspired by @airborn 's answer, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url) which also pointed me to [this module](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), which claims to solve this problem generically.

This example will apply a filter to ALL incoming requests, and allow you to redirect to wherever you want (similar to .htaccess functionality on apache).

Place the following line in the run function your *main dropwizard class* (the one that extends **`Service<AppConfiguration>` **

```
environment.addFilter(new UrlRewriteFilter(),"/*");
```

Place this class somewhere accessible to the above class

```
@WebFilter
public class UrlRewriteFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        // Place Redirection logic here (else continues the filter chain).
        if (redirectConditionTrue)
            String newURI = ""//New URl to do to;
            req.getRequestDispatcher(newURI).forward(req, res);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone reading this, note that the example UrlRewriteFilter class does **NOT** use the http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ Url-rewriter in anyway - it's just a standard Servlet filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Environment` in your `Service` class, you should be able to add a filter to Jetty. In this proxy filter, you should be able to detect those js files and redirect them to the new location.

Comment: I previously saw examples with a Filter, but non of them with dropwizard with the Environment.addFilter - so that was the missing part - thanks!
Attaching a more complete example to the Question...