# how can i use wild card to map url in java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want to achieve this:

```
http:\\localhost:8080\mysite\search\cotton\search.html
http:\\localhost:8080\mysite\search\bean\search.html
http:\\localhost:8080\mysite\search\cosmetic\search.html
http:\\localhost:8080\mysite\search\shoe\search.html


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>abcSearch</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/search/*/search.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

mean one pattern for the above all urls

can any one help out for me???

Comment: I surely hope you did not test with the backslashes in the URLs ?

Comment: Yes, they all go to abcSearch servlet. You can interpret the path and do your business logic accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The [rules for mappings](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) are as follows

> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is
>   used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix
>     is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to
>     the application's context root, i.e., requests of the form
>     `http://host:port/<context-root>/`. In this case the path info is ’/’
>     and the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default"
>     servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
>     request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
>
> All other strings are used for exact matches only.

So this

```
/search/*/search.html
```

would match exactly

```
http://host/context/search/*/search.html
```

You can't get path matching at the middle of the path with Servlet's url-patterns.

If you only have the 4 paths, I recommend you put 4 `<servlet-mapping>` element with each exact path match.

Comment: you mean http:\\localhost:8080\mysite\search\shoe\*.html,   but in this way i cannot handle the above scenario

Comment: @Danish Forget that suggestion. I was wrong. I recommend you use a `Filter` that matches all paths and dispatches accordingly.

Comment: @Danish Can't really type that up right now, but see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url). The `Filter` will read the path it's handling, determine the appropriate servlet and use it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change URLs like:

```
http:\\localhost:8080/mysite/search/cotton
http:\\localhost:8080/mysite/search/bean
http:\\localhost:8080/mysite/search/cosmetic
http:\\localhost:8080/mysite/search/shoe
```

or like that:

```
http:\\localhost:8080/mysite/cotton/search.html
http:\\localhost:8080/mysite/bean/search.html
```

For the first case pattern will be `<url-pattern>/search/*</url-pattern>` and for the second one `<url-pattern>*/search.html</url-pattern>`

Comment: With backslashes, these are still not URLs.