# How do I run multiple servlet after single submit button click?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I want to run two  servlet when I click  submit button in html page
Here is  servlet and  html code

```
package com.serv;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            String user=request.getParameter("user");
            out.println("<h2>"+user+"</h2>");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }

}
```

here is 2nd  servlet

```
package com.serv;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet2
 */
@WebServlet("/MyServlet2")
public class MyServlet2 extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out1=response.getWriter();
    try {
        String user1=request.getParameter("user1");
        out1.println("<h2>"+user1+"</h2>");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Here is HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="MyServlet">
        Name<input type="text" name="user">

    </form>
    <form method="post" action="MyServlet2">
        Sir Name<input type="text" name="user1">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

I tried placing submit button at different places but its not working . Can some tell me how shall i write the code so both  servlet will be called

Comment: a servlet can handle only one http request, you can create a filter(s) if you need pre-procecessing

Comment: What would be the use case for that? Usually there should be 1:1 mapping from request to servlet. If you want multiple things to happen, your servlet should make different calls into the business layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the request from one servlet to the other using

`Request.getRequestDispatcher(String).forward()` or 
`Request.getRequestDispatcher(String).include()`

based on how you would like to handle the response generated by the servlets. I'm not clear why are you getting `user` and `user1` parameter in different servlets. Instead do everything in a Single Servlet class. Please take a look at Servlet filters mainly intended to preliminary processing of the requests. Read about [Servlet Fiters](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-writing-filters.htm) to make use of them appropriately

Comment: I just want to display servlet contents

Comment: Yes you can make use of `include()` method to do it

Comment: I need to display both  servlet output at same time will it work ?

Comment: yes, it will just create a single response after the second servlet processes the request

Comment: I did following 
RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher(getServletName());
  rs.include(request, response);
its not working can you please tell what mistake i am doing ?

Comment: You have to provide the url mapped to the servlet in `request.getRequestDispatcher("/urlmappedtoservlet");`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49020/discussion-between-user1121210-and-octopus)

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to intercept the request with a filter, and forward to both doPost methods from it.

This could help you:

[How to use a servlet filter in Java to change an incoming servlet request url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url)

Another solution would be to make a forward from one servlet to the other. If you can modify the servlets, probably this is better than the filter.

Take a look at this:

http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/servlet/RequestDispatcher/forward.html

You could also resolve it sending two requests from the browser, using JavaScript, but I understand the scope of the problem is limited to Java.