# Dropwizard Multiple Rest API versions

Tags: java, dropwizard

Currently I am designing how to deal with routing in a versioned rest API where the version is not part of the url, but sent via a header variable.

I have considered/seen things like:

Re-writing the url based on the header variable i.e. the request `/orders {X-Media-Type: v1}` would rewrite to /v1/orders and then we could have a `@Path("/v1/orders") OrderV1Resource {}` and thus making v2 would be trivial `@Path("/v2/orders") OrderV2Resource {}`. (my first preference) [How to use a servlet filter in Java to change an incoming servlet request url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url)

Having a Single `@Path("/orders") OrderResource {}` where each of it's methods have an injected HeaderParam and I could check the header variable and then decide which Order API implementation I wanted to use (which seems very messy to me)

```
// pseudo-java code
@Path("/orders") 
OrderResource {
   OrderV1Impl v1Impl;
   OrderV2Impl v2Impl;
   @GET
   public List<Order> findAll(@HeaderParam header) {
       version = header.get("accepts")
       if(version.equals("v1")) { return v1Impl.findAll() }
       else if(version.equals("v2")) { return v2Impl.findAll() }
       return error
   }
}
```

Or just bundling them up in seperated JARS and having a service look at the header and route to the correct version. (seems to make sense if the app grows to be really large)

Comment: There is a discussion regarding this. Hope this helps https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/URL$20API$20Versioning$20dropwizard/dropwizard-user/Z8QA7cngzUo/5JTxc7wNt8wJ

Comment: @cemo clicking that link doesn't take me to the search results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing the version in via a header then used this to route the desired resource via a `javax.servlet.Filter`.

Example Accept header:
`Accept: application/vnd.datarank.v1+json`