# Spring MVC link with .jsp/.jsp suffix returns 404

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a simple page called headers.jsp in my Spring-MVC (4.1.5.RELEASE) web-app which i would like to call up from my index page like this:

```
<body>
<c:url value="/headers" var="headersUrl1"/>
<c:url value="/headers.jsp" var="headersUrl2"/>
<c:url value="/headers.jspx" var="headersUrl3"/>
<ul>
    <li><a href="${headersUrl1}">Works!</a></li>
    <li><a href="${headersUrl2}">Does not work!</a></li>
    <li><a href="${headersUrl3}">Does not work!</a></li>
</ul>
```

The first url (to /headers) works fine but the other two (with suffix .jsp/jspx) do not; result is a 404. I have a need for the links to work (in real life they come from a legacy database which i have to use). I have spent quite some time googling but found no solution as yet.
The requests to links are handled by the following controller code:

```
@Controller
public class HeadersViewController {

@RequestMapping(value = {"/headers"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getHeadersPage() {
    return "headers";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/headers**"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getHeaderPages() {
    return "headers";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/headers.jspx"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getHeaderPageJspx() {
    return "headers";
}

@RequestMapping("/{name}.jspx")
public String getPageByName(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
    return name;
}
}
```

None of the controller methods get called when requesting /headers.jsp or /headers.jspx.

Strangely enough when using spring-test and mock-mvc they do get fired and tests to check the mentioned url`s passes.
Any help greatly appreciated! The rest of the config code is given below.

Dispatcherservlet init:

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { SecurityConfiguration.class, WebMvcConfiguration.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[] { new HiddenHttpMethodFilter() };
}

}
```

MvcConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"nl.demo.web.controller"})
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index");
    registry.addViewController("/login");
    registry.addViewController("/logout");
}

@Bean 
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
      InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
      viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
      viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      viewResolver.setOrder(0);
      return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
}
 }
```

Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/images/**", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/fonts/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=1")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=1")
            .permitAll();
}


@Autowired
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    String user = "test";
    String password = "blabla";
    String[] roleList = "USER,SUPERVISOR".split(",");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser(user)
        .password(password)
        .roles(roleList);
}
}
```

Comment: can you try `.html` suffix in `c:url` and try without changing controller mapping.

Comment: yes, that works, also strangly enough, but i need the .jsp and .jspx suffix-es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of your issue is that the `*.jsp` and `*.jspx` extensions are normally handled by the container. If you for example checkout tomcat's `conf/web.xml` you'll notice a configuration

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern> 
  <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Similar goes for other containers. That is why your tests are working, yet your real app request fail.

Your best option would be to implement a Filter, that will be mapped to the same pattern, and that will redirect the `headers.jsp` and `headers.jspx`, to be handled by the controller, while leaving the other requests to be processed by the container as they would normally be, you have an example at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url)

Comment: This works for me, i have implemented a new Filter that forwards the request to the servletPath if the servletPath endswith .jsp/.jspx. Adding @WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*") as annotation the the Filter and adding it to the getServletFilters of the dispatcher init does the trick! Big thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your servlet is mapped to `/` and not to `/*`. `/` is a special mapping meaning that Spring MVC DispatcherServlet receives all requests **that have not been managed by anything else**.

As JSP and JSF are automatically registered servlets, the servlet container tries to pass the request to a JSP (resp. JSF) file and if it does not find it immediately sends a 404 and does not try to pass it to the DispatcherServlet.

You should map the dispatcher servlet to `/*`. But beware in that case, all URL will be given to the dispatcher servlet, and you will have to do a special treatment for serving static resources : you must add an override for `addResourceHandlers` to your Spring MVC configuration file (extract from Spring Framework Reference Manual - Serving of static resources) :

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/public-resources/");
}
```

Comment: Mapping the dispatcher to /* does not work for me because all other jsp's are not rendered.