# Shorten website url in a web.xml file. Using Jetty

Tags: servlets, jetty, web.xml

I'm trying to shorten the urls of my website in a web.xml file located on my Jetty server.

If my url is www.website.com/about.html

and I want to make it www.website.com/about

what would I need to add to web.xml?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend resorting to either a custom `javax.servlet.Filter` where you could just do a simple HTTP forward about to about.html.  You could then register that filter in your web.xml.

Another simpler option to checkout is this project which allows more complicated url rewriting.

https://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/

Comment: Thank you. How would I write this filter? Could you give me an example or show me where I might find one. I can't find anything on my specific issue.

Comment: Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url