# How to check request parameter is not empty String in @RequestMapping params?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, spring-annotations

In my controller I have String parameter, containing some id, that should not be null of empty string. I'm wondering, is there any way to check it is not empty String in @RequestMapping params?
I have tried to solve it in some ways

```
@RequestMapping(value = someURL, params = {"id"})
public SomeResponse doSomething(@RequestParam(required = true) String id)

@RequestMapping(value = someURL, params = {"!id="})
public SomeResponse doSomething(@RequestParam(required = true) String id)

@RequestMapping(value = someURL, params = {"!id=\"\""})
public SomeResponse doSomething(@RequestParam(required = true) String id)
```

with no success.
As I understand, both `params = {"id"}` and `@RequestParam(required = true)` can only check that parameter `id` is presented in request (!= null).

It is most likely that I have to check that with code in controller boby, like

```
if (id == null || id.isEmpty()) {
    return someErrorResponse;
}
```

but please correct me if I wrong.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. my app is running on Java 1.7 SE in Apache Tomcat 7.0.62 container

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the Spring code that consumes that annotation

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ServletAnnotationMappingUtils.checkParameters(String[], HttpServletRequest)
```

Something like this should work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = someURL, params = {"id!="})
public SomeResponse doSomething(@RequestParam(required = true) String id)
```

Comment: I noticed the 'required = true' isn't even necessary as I got a status 400 when I left out a header field: `{"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException","message":"Missing request header 'X-Custom-Header' for method parameter of type String","path":"/api/"}`

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I need. When I defined annotation the way you proposed, put breakpoint at the beginning of controller method and ran test, I a)didn't get into controller method; b)got self-explained exception org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "id!=" not met for actual request parameters: id={}.

Comment: WeGa how did u resolved it? Can you elaborate it please.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to be Java EE compliant with validations use `@Size(min=1)`.

Hibernate Validator has `@NotEmpty` annotation for this purpose. But that's not part of Java spec.

BTW, keep `required=true` as above notifications wouldn't enforce presence of the param in request.

**EDIT reaction on comment:**

Spring is Java EE Validation compliant, so @Size annotation should work if you have some Java EE validation API implmentor on class path. I used only hibernate validator so far. So you can enable these validation features by adding this into classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**than you can annotate your controller with `@Validated` annotation and do this:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = someURL, params = {"id"})
public SomeResponse doSomething(@RequestParam(required = true) @Size(min=1) String id)
```

You can also customize error message that will be sent to client.

If you are not familiar with Java EE validation, I would suggest to start looking into it as it's super important if you are creating REST/HTTP endpoint. It will open new world for you.

[Start with Java EE Tutorial for validation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partbeanvalidation.htm)

[Relevant part of Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-validation)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have update my post with environment description I have. I'm not sure it is compatible with the solution you have offered. Could you tell me, please, what would happened if input parameter violates these annotation constraints? How should I handle such situation in that case?

Answer (score -4):

You can use `defaultValue` as in

```
@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true, defaultValue = "-1") String id
```

But, again you'll have to use an if like

```
if(id.equals("-1")){
   return "someErrorPage"
}
```

Otherwise you can create a filter for this purpose, as given in this example

[How to use a servlet filter in Java to change an incoming servlet request url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for reply. But isn't my manual parameter check better than your solution?

Comment: Not only "not very helpful", but plain wrong. `defaultValue` is only used if the parameter is not specified, it doesn't cover the "was blank" scenario.