# Angular html5mode server rewrite wite spring mvc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

Can someone guide me on server rewrite in (AngularJS+spring mvc+tomcat server) app.

Till now I did following settings:

```
<base href="/Eatery/index.html">
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

**I don't have web.xml**

I am using java configuration in spring mvc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the answers from [How to use a servlet filter in Java to change an incoming servlet request url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url) I ended up with a Spring [OncePerRequestFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html).

It checks the incoming URLs whether they are for static resources (by extension) or whether they are calls to the REST api (with `/api/` substring) and allows them to be executed as usual. In other cases, it redirects to the `/index.html` so Angular's router can handle the request.

```
public class Html5ModeUrlSupportFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain)
                                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (isStatic(request) || isApi(request)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    private boolean isApi(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getRequestURI().indexOf("/api/") >= 0;
    }

    private boolean isStatic(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return Pattern.matches(".+\\.((html)|(css)|(js))$", request.getRequestURI());
    }
}
```

Of course, the rules of detecting requests must be adjusted to your needs.