# Tomcat CSRFFilter implementation in java

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I need to implement a CSRF filter in my application which is running on Tomcat 7. I have Used [Tomcat CSRF Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CSRF_Prevention_Filter) to make this filter works in my Application. I need to submit every action needs to encoded by [HttpServlet#encodeURL](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeURL(java.lang.String))

Since my application is very legacy there are lot of `jsp's` nearly 700 which are calling actions from jsp to jsp or jsp to servlet using Scriptlet tag or Javascript.

How to configure a filter or any kind of mechanism which makes every action which submitted to servlet will be encoded by `HttpServletResponse#encodeURL`

Anyway I have tried to implement a filter which will wraps `Servlet Request` with `encodedURL`,I have followed this link [Request URL Rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725165/3030406) as below.

```
public class UrlRewriteFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    //
}

 @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    final HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    final HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapped = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req) {
        @Override
        public StringBuffer getRequestURL() {
            final StringBuffer originalUrl = ((HttpServletRequest) req).getRequestURL();
            return new StringBuffer(res.encodeURL(req.getRequestURL()));
//I have added in above string Buffer building with including server path, but still no work
        }
    };
    chain.doFilter(wrapped, response);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    //
}
}
```

I have tried the above solution, **Still Not working**

Not working means The filter `CsrfPreventionFilter` is denying every request by returning `403` code.
if I submit any jsp with `response.encodeURL("url")` its working.

Please help to suggest anyway which i can write a filter.

Comment: Did you tried running this and is it working? What's the issue now?

Comment: @Isiva No its not working the filter is still denying requests.

Comment: Sorry not providing full answer. I use HandlerInterceptorAdapter (an Spring request listener) to generate a token if needed (GET) and to validate a token (POST) the token will be read from HttpSession and also set there if needed.
After the servlets methods you should fetch what is on session and setting on request. (Aspect programming could help here or some filter/listener)